# Mapbox resizing

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to resize a map after adjusting the size of it's container. The map does not adjust after calling `invalidateSize()`. In this example I want the map to shrink to the new container size. I have made a simple test case with Angular:

Index.html:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" ng-class="{'smaller': timedOut}">
            <mapbox map-id="jonfor.cifpucu09j2jos4m7h7dts4ek"></mapbox>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller.js:

```js
testController.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'mapboxService', '$timeout', function ($scope, mapboxService, $timeout) {
    mapboxService.init({accessToken:'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9uZm9yIiwiYSI6ImNpZnB1Y3Y0OGh0NnJyN2x4OHFqNzdoajUifQ.vg3xNMJH-RgzRAZF7RzhzQ'});
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope.timedOut = true;
        var map = mapboxService.getMapInstances()[0];
        map.invalidateSize();
        console.log("Timeout");
    }, 3000);
}]);
```

App.css:

```css
.smaller {
    width : 100px;
}
```

I also have put the project up on GitHub: https://github.com/Jonfor/MapBoxTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

[Angular Mapbox Directive](http://licyeus.github.io/angular-mapbox/) that you use instantiates the map with a [default width of 500px](https://github.com/licyeus/angular-mapbox/blob/master/dist/angular-mapbox.js#L315) if the width is not initially specified (through attribute `width="100"`).

You can fool it by specifying `width="dummyValue"`, so that it does not set a hard width on the map container, and the latter can adjust with its parent containers width, including when you modify it later on through CSS class.

Furthermore:

- You should read the previous map bounds *before* you make the width change.
- You have to use a nested timeout to give some time for your added CSS class to take effect (probably need a re-flow to happen) on your parent container width, before you call `invalidateSize()` and `fitBounds()` methods.

HTML:

```html
<mapbox map-id="jonfor.cifpucu09j2jos4m7h7dts4ek" width="dummyValue">
</mapbox>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$timeout(function() {
    //$scope.timedOut = true;
    var map = mapboxService.getMapInstances()[0];
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    $scope.timedOut = true;

    $timeout(function () {
      map.invalidateSize();
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }, 0);

    console.log("Timeout");
}, 2000);
```

Copied your code to Plunker with implemented modification: https://plnkr.co/edit/S91zxHYIxnZ72bSwyxXs?p=preview (with https so that you are happy! :-) )

---

Original answer:

I assume you would like the map to adjust its zoom level, so that the same content is visible after the container is resized?

In that case, you could simply remember the `map.getBounds()` before calling `map.invalidateSize()`, then request `map.fitBounds()` to have it adjusted to the previous content.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/3/

The `fitBounds` method will do its best to have the same content **at least** visible. If the new container ratio is different, more areas will also be visible. And because it has to use integer zoom levels, it may have to zoom out much further than required (if shrinking the container), or not zoom in at all (if expanding the container only in one dimension).

Just for the record, `map.invalidateSize()` is only a utility to have Leaflet taking into account the new container size for tiles loading (it does not load tiles that are too far away from the inside of the container) and vectors drawing among others. It does not change anything else visually. Try to *increase* the container size *without calling* for this function and see the "empty" area.

Comment: In your example, you modify the width directly. That is why it works. When I modify the width through an external stylesheet, my changes do not take affect.

Comment: I see that you are using the [Angular Mapbox Directive](http://licyeus.github.io/angular-mapbox/). How familiar are you with it, and possibly with [Angular Leaflet Directive](https://tombatossals.github.com/angular-leaflet-directive)? I will update the above answer.

Comment: Yes! the dummy value is perfect. Does exactly what I need.